# Generating binary matrix with fixed number of 1's

Tags: r, matrix, random

How can I generate a binary matrix that has the following behavior? I have came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461380/fast-way-to-create-a-binary-matrix-with-known-number-of-1-each-row-in-r) but it lacks the random positioning of the binary values.

```
## all rows contain four 1's at random column

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1     0
 [4,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     1
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
```

Comment: `t(replicate(5, sample(rep(c(1, 0), c(4, 6))), TRUE))`?

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: What about if I want to randomly assign different numbers of `1's` within a range of `2:4` to each row? e.g, `row1` has two `1s`, `row2` has four `1s` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be optimized but will get you going:

```
m<-matrix(data = rep(sample(rep(c(1,0),times=c(4,6))),times=5),byrow = T,nrow = 5,ncol = 10)
m<-apply(X = m,FUN = sample,MARGIN = 1)
m<-t(m)
```